# Fuzzing dynamic assigned ports with sulley

Tags: dynamic, port, fuzzing

I want to fuzz a network protocol with sulley. The problem is that the port I need to fuzz is dynamically chosen by the server. I use a pre_send function to contact the server and receive the dynamic port. I parsed the port number out of the response using re.
But now i am not able to set this port as destination port for the fuzzing data, because the destination port assignment...

```
target = sessions.target("10.10.10.10", 10000)
```

...already takes place before the pre_send function. Furthermore the port may be different every test case so this complicates it even more.

I thought about writing a standalone python script instead of the pre_send function and then change the destination port in the sulley-session-file and start it afterwards.
But then i would have to kill the session after every case and also it would be pretty ugly.

Did anybody ever came across something like this?
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Hrm, this is an odd problem that I haven't run into before.

As far as doing that, you probably need to roll that yourself if you chose to pursue that particular way. I don't think Sulley is capable of doing that in it's current form, but I'll keep that in mind and open a feature request for the next version.

I'm going to be re-writing Sulley in it's entirety some time in the future, there's too many silly things like this that should be doable.

What are you actually fuzzing? Is there any way to force it to use a single port?

Alternatively, you may be able to hook the connect() function to take another argument and force it to use the port you want.

Comment: I am fuzzing RTP. SIP sends the port number via the session description protocol.
I managed to get stuff running with a SIP direct call to another client which supports fixed ports.
But any application which doesn't allow defining fixed ports for RTP is still untestable.

Thanks for you help and I will post feature requests asap...

dynamo